# Is the absolute Galois group $\text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$ isomorphic to $\text{Gal}(K(S)/K)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-numbers, absolute-galois-group

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$, maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and uniformizer $\pi$. Let $\bar K$ be the algebraic closure of $K$ and $\bar{\mathfrak{m}}$ be the integral closure of $\mathfrak{m}$.

Let $f(x) \in x \mathcal{O}[[x]]$ be a noninvertible power series with finite Weirstrass-degree and let $f^{\circ n}(x)$ be the $n^\text{th}$ iterate of $f(x)$. We denote the set of roots of $f^{\circ n}(x)$ by $S_n=\{x \in \bar{\mathfrak{m}}~|~f^{\circ n}(x)=0 \}$. Also denote $S=\bigcup_n S_n$.

Since $f$ has finite Weierstrass degree, $\#S_n$ is finite. Assume that the field extension $K(S_n)$ is Galois such that \begin{align}\operatorname{Gal}(K(S_n)/K) \cong \left( \mathcal{O}/\pi^n \mathcal{O} \right)^{\times}.\tag{1}\label{1}\end{align}
Taking the inverse limit of the relation \eqref{1}, we get \begin{align} \operatorname{Gal}(\bar K/K) \cong  \mathcal{O}^{\times}.\tag{2}\label{2} \end{align}
There is a continuous surjection $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar K/K) \twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{Gal}(K(S_n)/K)$ by $\sigma \mapsto \sigma\rvert_{K(S_n)}$.

My question—

Suppose $g(x) \in x\mathcal{O}[[x]]$ be another power series such that there exists a $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(K(S_n)/K)$ satisfying \begin{align}\sigma(\alpha)=g(\alpha) ~~\text{for all  $\alpha \in S_n$} \tag{3} \label{3} \end{align} How can I extend the relation \eqref{3} to $$\sigma(\alpha)=g(\alpha)~~ \text{for all $\alpha \in S$ and $ \sigma \in \text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$}$$

Comment: Under this assumption it seems that the answer is no since the Galois group of $\overline{K}$ is nonabelian but the Galois group of $K(S)$ is (by assumption) abelian.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious?  Isn't the answer that the fibres of $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar K/K) \to \operatorname{Gal}(K(S)/K)$ are $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar K/K(S))$-torsors, so (regardless of what $K$ and $S$ are) cannot be trivial unless $K(S) = \bar K$?  Or do you mean whether there is some isomorphism other than the one given by restriction?

Comment: Why do you write ${\rm Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ on the left side of (2)? It would amount to saying $\overline{K} = K(S)$.

Comment: I admit I should not have written the left side of $(2)$. In other words, following the above nice comments, $\text{Gal}(\bar K/K) \neq \text{Aut}(K(S)/K)$. So now the question is- when would we get such equality ? Does adjoining `all roots of all iterates of all power series` $f(x) \in x \mathcal{O}[[x]]$ with $K$ produce $\bar K$  or the $\text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$ ?

Comment: Can you simply edit this question to ask only what you intend to ask, rather than leaving the old material up, which makes it a bit confusing? If you ask for all roots of all iterates of all power series, that would be enough, since every finite extension is generated by the roots of some polynomial, thus of some power series.

Comment: @WillSawin, well. Suppose $g(x) \in x\mathcal{O}[[x]]$ be another power series so that $\sigma(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$ for all $ \alpha \in S_n$ and $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(K(S_n)/K)$. I want to show this relation can be extended to $\sigma(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha \in S$ and $ \sigma \in \text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$.   This is what I want. When does it follow ?

Comment: Equation (3) is also certainly false, as to be true for all $\sigma$s would imply that $\sigma(\alpha)$ is independent of $\sigma$, which, since this is also true for all $\alpha \in S_n$,  only holds if the Galois group is trivial.

Comment: @WillSawin, no, perhaps I made mistake in the language. I mean there exists `at least one` $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(K(S_n)/K)$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha \in S_n$. I didn't mean   all $\sigma$ will do it. Now I want to show whether that particular $\sigma$  correspond to some $\tau \in \text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$ satisfying relation like $(3)$. All I confirm is that the relation $(3)$ is valid.

Comment: I don't find reason why to close this question. When I said there exists $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(K(S_n)/K)$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha \in S_n$ is quite possible. I find no reason to disagree. In fact this is an established fact in a published paper in a reputed journal.